# Make a password generator

Tags: c#, passwords

I am currently trying to make a random password generator.
My code works fine if I only pick one type of symbols.

What's the best way to make my code to word for more than one type?
Also what parameters would you add to make the password more secured?
I am thinking of adding an if loop to check if there are more than two same letters, symbols or numbers in a row.

That's how my interface looks like:

[image]

and that is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Max number of identical characters in a row 
    const int Maximum_Identical = 2;
    // lower case chars
    const string lower_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    // capital chars
    const string capital_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    // numbers
    const string numbers = "0123456789";
    // symbols
    const string symbols = @"!#$%&*@\";
    // password lenght 
    int lenght;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //use stringbuilder so I can add more chars later
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
        //take max lenght from numericUpDown
        lenght = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
        // random instance so I can use Next and don't get loops
        Random rdm = new Random();

        if (small_letters__Box.Checked)
        {
            //add a random small character to pass untill it reaches the selected lenght  
            while (lenght-- > 0 )
            {
                password.Append(lower_chars[rdm.Next(lower_chars.Length)]);
            }
        }

        if (capital_letters__Box.Checked)
        {
            //add a random capital character to pass untill it reaches the selected lenght  
            while (lenght-- > 0)
            {
                password.Append(capital_chars[rdm.Next(capital_chars.Length)]);
            }
        }

        if (numbers_Box.Checked)
        {
            //add a random character to pass untill it reaches the selected lenght  
            while (lenght-- > 0)
            {
                password.Append(numbers[rdm.Next(numbers.Length)]);
            }
        }

        if (symbols_Box.Checked)
        {
            //add a random character to pass untill it reaches the selected lenght  
            while (lenght-- > 0)
            {
                password.Append(symbols[rdm.Next(symbols.Length)]);
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = password.ToString();
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I would not allow a password length of 1 as an option ;)

Answer (score 3):

below code is my already written code which I wrote more than a couple of years ago and I still use it in my many of my projects where needed, it covers all you are in need of

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public static class ArrayExtentions
{
    public static object[] Shuffle(this object[] array)
    {
        var alreadySwaped = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>();
        var rndLoopCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(Convert.ToInt32(array.Length / 4), Convert.ToInt32((array.Length / 2) + 1));

        for (var i = 0; i <= rndLoopCount; i++)
        {
            int rndIndex1 = 0, rndIndex2 = 0;
            do
            {
                rndIndex1 = RandomUtils.GetRandom(0, array.Length);
                rndIndex2 = RandomUtils.GetRandom(0, array.Length);
            } while (alreadySwaped.Contains(new Tuple<int, int>(rndIndex1, rndIndex2)));

            alreadySwaped.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(rndIndex1, rndIndex2));
            var swappingItem = array[rndIndex1];
            array[rndIndex1] = array[rndIndex2];
            array[rndIndex2] = swappingItem;
        }
        return array;
    }

}

public class RandomUtils
{
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> RndLocal = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random(GetUniqueSeed()));

    private static int GetUniqueSeed()
    {
        long next, current;
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        var seed = BitConverter.ToInt64(guid, 0);

        do
        {
            current = Interlocked.Read(ref seed);
            next = current * BitConverter.ToInt64(guid, 3);
        } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref seed, next, current) != current);

        return (int)next ^ Environment.TickCount;
    }

    public static int GetRandom(int min, int max)
    {
        Contract.Assert(max >= min);
        return RndLocal.Value.Next(min, max);
    }

    public static int GetRandom(int max)
    {
        return RndLocal.Value.Next(max);
    }

    public static double GetRandom()
    {
        return RndLocal.Value.NextDouble();
    }
}

public class StringUtility
{
    private const string UpperAlpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";
    private const string LowerAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz";
    private const string Numbers = "0123456789";
    private const string SpecialChars = "~!@#$%^&*()_-+=.?";


    private static string CreateSourceString(bool includeLowerCase, bool includeUpperCase, bool includenumbers, bool includeSpChars)
    {
        Contract.Assert(includeLowerCase || includeUpperCase || includenumbers || includeSpChars);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (includeLowerCase) sb.Append(LowerAlpha);
        if (includeUpperCase) sb.Append(UpperAlpha);
        if (includenumbers) sb.Append(Numbers);
        if (includeSpChars) sb.Append(SpecialChars);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static string GenerateString(string sourceString, int length = 6)
    {
        var rndString = Shuffle(sourceString);
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            builder.Append(rndString[RandomUtils.GetRandom(0, rndString.Length)]);
        return builder.ToString();
    }
    public static string GenerateRandomString(int length = 6,
        bool includenumbers = false,
        bool includeSpChars = false)
    {
        var sourceStr = CreateSourceString(true, true, includenumbers, includeSpChars);
        return GenerateString(sourceStr, length);
    }


    public static string GenerateRandomString(int minLength,
        int maxLength,
        bool includenumbers = false,
        bool includeSpChars = false)
    {
        if (maxLength < minLength) maxLength = minLength;
        var len = RandomUtils.GetRandom(minLength, maxLength + 1);
        return GenerateRandomString(len, includenumbers, includeSpChars);
    }

    public static string Shuffle(string str)
    {
        var alreadySwaped = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>();
        var rndLoopCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(Convert.ToInt32(str.Length / 4), Convert.ToInt32((str.Length / 2) + 1));
        var strArray = str.ToArray();
        for (var i = 0; i <= rndLoopCount; i++)
        {
            int rndIndex1 = 0, rndIndex2 = 0;
            do
            {
                rndIndex1 = RandomUtils.GetRandom(0, str.Length);
                rndIndex2 = RandomUtils.GetRandom(0, str.Length);
            } while (alreadySwaped.Contains(new Tuple<int, int>(rndIndex1, rndIndex2)));

            alreadySwaped.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(rndIndex1, rndIndex2));
            var swappingChar = strArray[rndIndex1];
            strArray[rndIndex1] = strArray[rndIndex2];
            strArray[rndIndex2] = swappingChar;
        }
        return new string(strArray);
    }

    public static string GeneratePassword(PasswordComplexity complexityLevel)
    {
        switch (complexityLevel)
        {
            case PasswordComplexity.Simple: return GenerateSimplePassword();
            case PasswordComplexity.Medium: return GenerateMediumPassword();
            case PasswordComplexity.Strong: return GenerateStrongPassword();
            case PasswordComplexity.Stronger: return GenerateStrongerPassword();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static string GenerateSimplePassword()
    {
        return GenerateRandomString(6, 9);
    }

    private static string GenerateMediumPassword()
    {
        var passLen = RandomUtils.GetRandom(6, 10);
        var numCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(1, 3);
        var alphaStr = GenerateRandomString(passLen - numCount);
        var numStr = GenerateString(Numbers, numCount);
        var pass = alphaStr + numStr;
        return Shuffle(pass);
    }

    private static string GenerateStrongPassword()
    {
        var lowerCharCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(2, 5);
        var upperCharCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(2, 5);
        var numCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(2, 4);
        var spCharCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(2, 4);

        var lowerAlphaStr = GenerateString(LowerAlpha, lowerCharCount);
        var upperAlphaStr = GenerateString(UpperAlpha, upperCharCount);
        var spCharStr = GenerateString(SpecialChars, spCharCount);
        var numStr = GenerateString(Numbers, numCount);
        var pass = lowerAlphaStr + upperAlphaStr + spCharStr + numStr;
        return Shuffle(pass);
    }

    private static string GenerateStrongerPassword()
    {
        var lowerCharCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(5, 12);
        var upperCharCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(4, 8);
        var numCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(4, 6);
        var spCharCount = RandomUtils.GetRandom(4, 6);

        var lowerAlphaStr = GenerateString(LowerAlpha, lowerCharCount);
        var upperAlphaStr = GenerateString(UpperAlpha, upperCharCount);
        var spCharStr = GenerateString(SpecialChars, spCharCount);
        var numStr = GenerateString(Numbers, numCount);
        var pass = lowerAlphaStr + upperAlphaStr + spCharStr + numStr;
        return Shuffle(Shuffle(pass));
    }

    public enum PasswordComplexity
    {
        Simple, Medium, Strong, Stronger
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your password generation has 2 steps.

1. Determine the character set
2. Create a password randomly from the character set of length n

Function 1 creates the character set:

```
// Make sure you have using System.Linq;
private List<char> GetCharacterSet()
{
    IEnumerable<char> returnSet = new char[]{};

    if (small_letters__Box.Checked)
    {
        returnSet = returnSet.Append(lower_chars);
    }

    if (capital_letters__Box.Checked)
    {
        returnSet = returnSet.Append(capital_chars);
    }

    if (numbers_Box.Checked)
    {
        returnSet = returnSet.Append(numbers);
    }

    if (symbols_Box.Checked)
    {
        returnSet = returnSet.Append(symbols);
    }

    return returnSet.ToList();
}
```

Function 2 creates a password of given length from your character set

```
private string GetPassword(int length, List<char> characterSet)
{
    if(characterSet.Count < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("characterSet contains no items!");
    }

    if(length < 1)
    {
        return "";
    }

    Random rdm = new Random();

    StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        int charIndex = rdm.Next(0, characterSet.Count)
        password.Append(characterSet[charIndex]);
    }

    return password.ToString();
}
```

Then simply rig your button click event handler to call these functions and display the resulting password.

Comment: There is a problem with this code, if you select all boxes, there is a possibility that for instance you get a password without capitals, or without symbols. To solve this, you have to pick random characters from each selected charachtersets to be sure that if a box is checked you get those characters.

Comment: True, I suppose it depends on the rules OP wants to define. There may be some character sets you wouldn't want to impose this restriction on. OP adds another checkbox for including the character `=` in a password. Checking this box shouldn't necessarily always include an `=`.

Answer (score 0):

I write this code for you. You can just copy and use it. All of my code is just a method that you can pass appropriate arguments and it gives you back a completely randomized password. I test it several times before answering your question, It works well.

```
private string GeneratePassword(bool useCapitalLetters, bool useSmallLetters, bool useNumbers, bool useSymbols, int passLenght)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

        //This for loop is for selecting password chars in order 
        for (int i = 0;;)
        {
            if (useCapitalLetters)
            {
                password.Append((char)random.Next(65, 91)); //Capital letters 
                ++i; if (i >= passLenght) break;
            }
            if (useSmallLetters)
            {
                password.Append((char)random.Next(97, 122)); //Small letters
                ++i; if (i >= passLenght) break;
            }
            if (useNumbers)
            {
                password.Append((char)random.Next(48, 57)); //Number letters
                ++i; if (i >= passLenght) break;
            }
            if (useSymbols)
            {
                password.Append((char)random.Next(35, 38)); //Symbol letters
                ++i; if (i >= passLenght) break;
            }
        }

        //This for loop is for disordering password characters
        for (int i = 0; i < password.Length; ++i)
        {
            int randomIndex1 = random.Next(password.Length);
            int randomIndex2 = random.Next(password.Length);
            char temp = password[randomIndex1];
            password[randomIndex1] = password[randomIndex2];
            password[randomIndex2] = temp;
        }

        return password.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go :

```
        string[] charList =
        {
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
            "0123456789",
            "@\"!#$%&*@\\"
        };

        int desiredPasswordLength = 12;
        var randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        string generatedPassword = "";

        for (int i = randomNumberGenerator.Next() % 4; desiredPasswordLength > 0; i = (i+1) % 4)
        {

            var takeRandomChars = randomNumberGenerator.Next() % 3;
            for (int j = 0; j < takeRandomChars; j++)
            {
                var randomChar = randomNumberGenerator.Next() % charList[i].Length;
                char selectedChar = charList[i][randomChar % charList[i].Length];
                generatedPassword = string.Join("", generatedPassword, selectedChar);
            }

            desiredPasswordLength -= takeRandomChars;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Generated password: {0}",generatedPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

an answer with complete randomize char and using the max repeat of char, i have added a shuffle string function:

```
        const int Maximum_Identical = 2; // Max number of identical characters in a row 
        const string lower_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // lower case chars
        const string capital_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //capital chars
        const string numbers = "0123456789"; //numbers
        const string symbols = @"!#$%&*@\"; //symbols
        int lenght = 6; //

        bool lowercase = true, capital=true, num=true, sym=true;

        List<char[]> PasswordSet = new List<char[]>();
        List<char[]> charSet = new List<char[]>();
        List<int[]> countSet = new List<int[]>();

        if (lowercase) charSet.Add(lower_chars.ToArray());
        if (capital) charSet.Add(capital_chars.ToArray());
        if (num) charSet.Add(numbers.ToArray());
        if (sym) charSet.Add(symbols.ToArray());

        foreach(var c in charSet)
            countSet.Add(new int[c.Length]);

        Random rdm = new Random();
        //we create alist with each type with a length char (max repeat char included)
        for(int i = 0; i < charSet.Count;i++)
        {
            var lng = 1;
            var p0 = "";
            while (true)
            {
                var ind = rdm.Next(0, charSet[i].Length);
                if (countSet[i][ind] < Maximum_Identical )
                {
                    countSet[i][ind] += 1;
                    lng++;
                    p0 += charSet[i][ind];
                }
                if (lng == lenght) break;
            }
            PasswordSet.Add(p0.ToArray());
        }

        //generate a password with the desired length with at less one char in desired type,
        //and we choose randomly in desired type to complete the length of password
        var password = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        {
            char p;
            if (i < PasswordSet.Count)
            {                   
                int id;
                do
                {
                    id = rdm.Next(0, PasswordSet[i].Length);
                    p = PasswordSet[i][id];
                } while (p == '\0');
                password += p;
                PasswordSet[i][id] = '\0';
            }
            else
            {
                int id0;
                int id1;
                do
                {
                    id0 = rdm.Next(0, PasswordSet.Count);
                    id1 = rdm.Next(0, PasswordSet[id0].Length);
                    p = PasswordSet[id0][id1];
                } while (p == '\0');
                password += p;
                PasswordSet[id0][id1] = '\0';
            }
        }

        //you could shuffle the final password
        password = Shuffle.StringMixer(password);
```

shuffle string function:

```
static class Shuffle
{
    static System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

    static void Fisher_Yates(int[] array)
    {
        int arraysize = array.Length;
        int random;
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
        {
            random = i + (int)(rnd.NextDouble() * (arraysize - i));

            temp = array[random];
            array[random] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static string StringMixer(string s)
    {
        string output = "";
        int arraysize = s.Length;
        int[] randomArray = new int[arraysize];

        for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
        {
            randomArray[i] = i;
        }

        Fisher_Yates(randomArray);

        for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
        {
            output += s[randomArray[i]];
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static string GeneratorPassword(UInt16 length = 8)
    {
        const string chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        Random rnd = new Random();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int index = 0;
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                index = rnd.Next(0, 10);
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 1)
            {
                index = rnd.Next(10, 36);
            }
            else
            {
                index = rnd.Next(36, 62);
            }
            sb.Insert(rnd.Next(0, sb.Length), chars[index].ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int j= 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( GeneratorPassword());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?